# spring boot with cluster redis in docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster

I have redis container in docker, and if it the mode is stand alone then adding this properties

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6386
```

in the the props file works just fine and I can read/write to redis.

but if i enabled the cluster mode on the container
and added the following property to the props

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=127.0.0.1:6386
```

gives this error when using redis template!
aused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:6386

and if i created multiple containers (same network)
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=127.0.0.1:6379,127.0.0.1:6382,127.0.0.1:6383,127.0.0.1:6384,127.0.0.1:6385,127.0.0.1:6386
I am getting timeout on using redis template.
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /172.30.0.2:6384
at

I am using:
1- Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE
2- Redis 7.2.1

Comment: which spring boot, redis version are you using ?

Comment: @AbdelghaniRoussi 
1- Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE
2- Redis 7.2.1

Comment: Probably you don't need redis cluster. look for "redis sentinel" instead of redis cluster.